# how to create a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

when I click  button1 should print A s but when I click button2 need to stop thread1 and need to start thread2, what is the wrong in here please help me

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (thread2.IsAlive)
        {
            thread2.Suspend();
        }
        thread1 = new Thread(threadOne);
        thread1.Start();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (thread1.IsAlive)
        {
            thread1.Suspend();
        }
        thread2 = new Thread(threadTwo);
        thread2.Start();
    }

    private void threadOne() {
        for (int i=0; i < 20; i++ )
        {
            Console.Write("A");
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }

    private void threadTwo()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("B");
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's quite a lot wrong, as the other posters have correctly pointed out.  I would add this:

1) Most threads in commercial-grade software never terminate during the lifetime of the application - they are written as infinite loops with blocking calls that wait for some sort of signaling from other threads or I/O operations.

2) Continual create/terminate/destroy of thread objects is expensive, difficult to control, awkward-to-debug, unreliable and generally causes pain.

3) If your multithread code contains any of the following:

```
Suspend()
Resume(), (except in some thread ctors)
Join()
Abort()
IsAlive()
```

You should probably think again :)

I know you're only learning, but sometimes it's better to patch up holes before they get any bigger :)

Answer (score 1):

You are creating instance of Thread's in the Button Click events, so the if statement that checks threadX.IsAlive will throw error reporting null reference exception

So please create the instance of thread1 & 2 on load

Answer (score 1):

Check for `null` also.
Use `Abort()` method instead of Suspend() as you are anyway creating a new thread each time.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (thread2!=null && thread2.IsAlive)
        {
            thread2.Abort();
        }
        thread1 = new Thread(threadOne);
        thread1.Start();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (thread1!=null && thread1.IsAlive)
        {
            thread1.Abort();
        }
        thread2 = new Thread(threadTwo);
        thread2.Start();
    }
```

Comment: Thread.abort is dangerous.  See http://haacked.com/archive/2004/11/12/how-to-stop-a-thread.aspx or do a web search.